# defining groups, then sub-groups

Tags: r

I need to move my python code to R and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of setting this up in R.

I have items that make up a main group. For instance, When an exact food is present, the main group (fruits, pastry), along with the exact food, appears in the report.

### Type   |  Food

Fruits |  orange

Fruits |  apple

Pasty  |  morning bun

This is small example:

```
Fruits = ['orange', 'apple', 'grapes']
group1 = worksheet_rt.loc[df['item'].isin(Fruits)]

Pastry = ['croissant', 'morning bun']
group2 = worksheet_rt.loc[df['item'].isin(Pastry)]

Food = ['Fruits', 'Pastry'] 

worksheet.food = pd.concat([group1, group2], keys=Food, axis=0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by exact food? Can you create a reproducible example in R using `dput` and show what your expected output would look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want...

You can store your data in a tibble:

```
tibble::tibble(Type = c("fruit", "fruit", "pastry"),
               Food = c("orange", "apple", "morning bun"))
```

... or a data.frame:

```
data.frame(Type = c("fruit", "fruit", "pastry"),
           Food = c("orange", "apple", "morning bun"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you have observed food items (what you call 'exact' items) and need to assign them to food categories. If that's correct then you can proceed like this:

First your observed items, in any order:

```
food_item <- c("apple", "orange", "croissant", "grapes", "bun", "croissant", "orange", "apple")
```

Now the categories the itmes belong to: these can be determned by using an ifelse clause which defines, in this case, all fruits as `fruit`and anything else that does not satisfy the condition as `pastry`:

```
food_type <- ifelse(food_item=="apple"|food_item=="orange"|food_item=="grapes", "fruit", "pastry")
```

And finally you may want to assemble the two vectors in a dataframe:

```
df_food <- data.frame(food_item, food_type); df_food
  food_item food_type
1     apple     fruit
2    orange     fruit
3 croissant    pastry
4    grapes     fruit
5       bun    pastry
6 croissant    pastry
7    orange     fruit
8     apple     fruit
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that's what my python code does--observed food items that get assigned to food categories. The only issue I see with the above code is that it'll be very hard to scale. I have almost 3000 food items and 300 food categories. Some food items will belong to multiple categories.